# Azure OpenID Connect - Keep user out of azure portal

Tags: azure, openid-connect

After successfully signing in a user to an app (using Azure AD -  OIDC ),  User can navigate to **dashboard** of "**portal.azure.com**"

Is there way to keep the user out of **portal.azure.com** once the app has created the ClaimsPrincipal?

Answer (score 0):

If the user exists in an Azure AD tenant, they can log in to the Azure Portal.
Whether they can do things is a different story.

In order to create or modify or even see resources, the user would need to be assigned a role in a subscription, resource group or resource.
Without one, they cannot see or do anything for Azure resources.

As for Azure AD things, users of type Member have basic access to see user lists and group lists for example.
Guest users (invited from other Azure AD tenants) can have their rights limited by setting certain settings in the User Settings -> External collaboration settings for your Azure AD tenant.
For example, you can disable user enumeration so Guests cannot see other users' info.

On the User Settings blade, you can also restrict access to the Azure AD management portal for non-admins, however it won't really take away their rights to see other users for example, it will just remove non-administrator access to the management area for Azure AD in Azure Portal.
They could still get a list of users with other tools like Azure AD PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was hoping there was an easy way to use Azure AD just for OpenID Connect to obtain claims for an app without exposing the user to the azure portal.